# Phoenix JDBC query - why not synchronizing queries between users?

Tags: java, node.js, jdbc, apache-phoenix

the problem is when i send request in multiple users the queries aren't executed simultaneous which making the second user waiting for the first user to get respond from the server then executes hes queries ,

the sample code about the query

```
   _this.query = function(sql) {
    console.log("query");
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

      try {
        _this.conn.createStatement(function(err, statement) {
          if (err) {
            reject(err);
          } else {
            console.log("created statement");
            statement.executeQuery(sql, function(err, resultset) {
              console.log("execute query");
              if (err) {
                reject(err);
              } else {
                resultset.toObjArray(function(errRes, results) {
                  if (errRes) reject(errRes);
                  else resolve(results);
                });
              }
            });
          }
        });
      } catch (e) {
        reject(e);
      }
    });
  };
```

this is the response from that query for 2 users as you can see the first one executes while the second one waits till the first get the respond 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7LOkx.png)

this is the jdbc config

```
var config = {
  drivername: "org.apache.phoenix.jdbc.PhoenixDriver",
  // url: 'jdbc:phoenix:pPhoenix0:2181:/hbase-unsecure',
  url:"jdbc:phoenix:localhost:2181:/hbase-unsecure",
  user: "",
  password: "",
  // minpoolsize: 10,
  maxpoolsize: 100
};
```

Comment: What is `_this`?

Comment: this is connection with database using phoenix and jdbc